# Simplifying $\sin(nx)$ series notation

Tags: infinite-product, trigonometric-series

I am attempting to simplify the following notation:
$$\sin(nx)=\sin(x)\left(2^{n-1}\cos^{n-1}(x)-\frac{n-2}{1!}2^{n-3}\cos^{n-3}(x)+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)2^{n-5}\cos^{n-5}(x)}{2!}+\cdots\right)$$
I recognise the powers increased by odd terms,  so I have summarised the equation up to
$$\sin(x)\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n-(2m+1)}\cos^{n-(2m+1)}(x)\prod_{i=2}^{m+2}(n-i)}{m!}\right)$$
However, the product
$$\prod_{i=2}^{m+2}(n-i)$$
starts at $n-2$ but the initial value should begin at $1$, therefore, what is the best approach for product notation, or alternative to simplyfing the above equation?

Comment: What does this have to do with inner products? Please check which tag is for what before putting them.

Comment: @bb_823 was supposed to be infinite products

Comment: I think the sum over m should go to $\lfloor \frac{n-1}2 \rfloor $ rather than to infinity

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is $\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-m-2)!}$. When $m=0$ this evaluates to $1$. When $m=1$ this evaluates to $\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-3)!}=n-2$. etc.
When you combine this with the already present $m!$ in the denominator, you have the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-2}{m}$

However, I will say your formula does not look right. What you are trying to calculate is the chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, which has explicit formula listed [wolfram mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html)

Comment: Excellent remark on the fact that the given relationship is a "disguise" of the representation of Chebyshev $U_n(t)$ where $t=\cos(x)$.

Comment: Thanks this is what I required, with modification to the summation $\sum_{r=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(-1)^r \binom{n-r-1}{r}2^{n-2r-1}x^{n-2r-1}$